# Show that the localization $k[t]_{(t)}$ is a valuation ring

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, valuation-theory

I want to see that $B=k[t]_{(t)}$ is a valuation ring. To show this I need to show that for every $x\in \operatorname{Frac}(B)$ we have at least one of $x\in B$ or $x^{-1}\in B$.
Intuitively i think $\operatorname{Frac}(B)$ should be $k(t)$ but I can't think of succinct way of showing this.

Let $x\in k(t)$ then $x=f/g$ with $f,g\in k[t]$. An element $y\in B$ looks like $h/t^n$. So we need to show that $f/g=h/t^n$ or $g/f=h/t^n$. I think we I should try use that $k[t]$ is a UFD and get a nice relation between $f$ and $g$. We can assume $f,g$ to be coprime,but even them I'm not sure ho we can deal with something like this $x=\frac{t-1}{t-2}$. If we could show that that $t$ must divide $f$ or $g$ we would be done but I am not sure if this is true.

Questions:
Why is $\operatorname{Frac}(B)=k(t)$?
Why can we assume $t$ must divide $f$ or $g$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$k[t]_{(t)}$ is a localization of $k[t]$, so it is canonically a subring of $\operatorname{Frac} k[t]=k(t)$. If $F$ were any field containing $k[t]_{(t)}$ properly contained in $k(t)$, this would contradict the fact that $k[t]$ has fraction field $k(t)$.

Your second problem has a key misunderstanding: $k[t]_{(t)}$ is defined to be the localization at the set of elements not in $(t)$, **not** the localization at $\{1,t,t^2,t^3,\cdots\}$. So $x$ is already in $k[t]_{(t)}$, for instance. Try again with this new information - I've put a full explanation under a spoiler below for you.

> If $f/g\in k(t)$ is written in lowest terms, then $t$ divides at most one of $f$ and $g$. If $t$ does not divide $g$, then $g\notin (t)$ so $f/g$ is already a member of $k[t]_{(t)}$. If $t$ divides $g$, then $t$ doesn't divide $f$, so $g/f$ is in $k[t]_{(t)}$.

Comment: I know how to get the result if we know that $t$ divides $f$ or $g$ but why does $t$ divide $f$ or $g$?

Comment: @MarkMurray it doesn't have to! Your example with $x$ in your post shows this.

Comment: ah thank you, If $t$ doesn't divide either $f$ or $g$ then $f/g$ is in $B$. I see know what you meant by key misunderstanding